# remove black dashed lines from image stitching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, homography

I am stitching multiple images. While stitching two images it is showing dashed black line in between stitching like below.
[image]

Has anyone knows about this how I can remove or get rid of this black dashed line ?

main part of stitching code which stitches two images and calls next image with result of previous stitched images untill all images gets over:

```
detector = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret1, mask1 = cv2.threshold(gray1,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kp1, descriptors1 = detector.detectAndCompute(gray1,mask1)

gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret2, mask2 = cv2.threshold(gray2,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kp2, descriptors2 = detector.detectAndCompute(gray2,mask2)

keypoints1Im = cv2.drawKeypoints(image1, kp1, outImage = cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DEFAULT, color=(0,0,255))
util.display("KEYPOINTS",keypoints1Im)
keypoints2Im = cv2.drawKeypoints(image2, kp2, outImage = cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DEFAULT, color=(0,0,255))
util.display("KEYPOINTS",keypoints2Im)

matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors2,descriptors1, k=2)

good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.55 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

print (str(len(good)) + " Matches were Found")

if len(good) <= 10:
    return image1

matches = copy.copy(good)

matchDrawing = util.drawMatches(gray2,kp2,gray1,kp1,matches)
util.display("matches",matchDrawing)

src_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

A = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(src_pts,dst_pts,fullAffine=False)

if A is None:
    HomogResult = cv2.findHomography(src_pts,dst_pts,method=cv2.RANSAC)
    H = HomogResult[0]

height1,width1 = image1.shape[:2]
height2,width2 = image2.shape[:2]

corners1 = np.float32(([0,0],[0,height1],[width1,height1],[width1,0]))
corners2 = np.float32(([0,0],[0,height2],[width2,height2],[width2,0]))

warpedCorners2 = np.zeros((4,2))

for i in range(0,4):
    cornerX = corners2[i,0]
    cornerY = corners2[i,1]
    if A is not None: #check if we're working with affine transform or perspective transform
        warpedCorners2[i,0] = A[0,0]*cornerX + A[0,1]*cornerY + A[0,2]
        warpedCorners2[i,1] = A[1,0]*cornerX + A[1,1]*cornerY + A[1,2]
    else:
        warpedCorners2[i,0] = (H[0,0]*cornerX + H[0,1]*cornerY + H[0,2])/(H[2,0]*cornerX + H[2,1]*cornerY + H[2,2])
        warpedCorners2[i,1] = (H[1,0]*cornerX + H[1,1]*cornerY + H[1,2])/(H[2,0]*cornerX + H[2,1]*cornerY + H[2,2])

allCorners = np.concatenate((corners1, warpedCorners2), axis=0)

[xMin, yMin] = np.int32(allCorners.min(axis=0).ravel() - 0.5)
[xMax, yMax] = np.int32(allCorners.max(axis=0).ravel() + 0.5)

translation = np.float32(([1,0,-1*xMin],[0,1,-1*yMin],[0,0,1]))
warpedResImg = cv2.warpPerspective(image1, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))


if A is None:
    fullTransformation = np.dot(translation,H) #again, images must be translated to be 100% visible in new canvas
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, fullTransformation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))

else:
    warpedImageTemp = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpAffine(warpedImageTemp, A, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))

result = np.where(warpedImage2 != 0, warpedImage2, warpedResImg)
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Edit:

Input image1(resized)

[image]

Input image2(resized)

[image]

Result(resized)

[image]

**Update:**

Result after @fmw42 anwser:

[image]

Comment: As a guess, I suspect it is "warpedImage2 != 0" in your last line `result = np.where(warpedImage2 != 0, warpedImage2, warpedResImg)`. You are getting staircase aliasing from that binary decision at the edge. The edges from the two sides are likely anti-aliased with black from the interpolation so they have some black mixed with the actual colors. You could try some tests. Do your warpAffine with nearest neighbor interpolation and see what happens at those seams. Also you could try use "warpedImage2 < threshold" and see if that helps or makes it worse. Try different thresholds with low values.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for response. I am not pro in this so not understood properly your comment. But I have tried `warpedImage2 = cv2.warpAffine(warpedImageTemp, A, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin),cv2.INTER_NEAREST)` and `ret1, mask1 = cv2.threshold(gray1,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` still that black line not removed. Please let me know if possible what I need to change and test.

Comment: One thing to try is different flags (interpolations) in cv2.warpAffine(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87 and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121ac97d8e4880d8b5d509e96825c7522deb

Comment: Another thing to try is to change `warpedImage2 != 0` to `warpedImage2 <T` in `result = np.where(warpedImage2 != 0, warpedImage2, warpedResImg)` where you set T to different values. Start at 32. See what happens. Then either double or half it and see what happens.

Comment: @ fmw42 with T=64 and above result image is as shown in question. With other changes not getting right result.

Comment: The code example is a bit long to likely be a minimal example. Are you sure that you need all the presented code to reproduce the problem? If not please minimize it further.

Comment: @Trilarion As I am new to this topic, I am not sure which code part/code line is causing that black line to produce but above code is main/core steps of stitching which is following everywhere.

Comment: You could leave out parts of the code until the black line is not visible anymore and then go back one step. That would make the example smaller. Even without inside knowledge a bit of try and error is possible to isolate the error a bit further. Additionally you would have to produce example images to stitch, otherwise the example cannot be run. The code could be fine and it could be a problem with the input data instead. You also could have run the code with different input images and check this. If there wouldn't be a bounty on it, I would probably close vote as need more debugging details.

Comment: `@ganesh` You do not understand about the threshold. I was not asking you to threshold the image. I wanted you to change your test to `result = np.where(warpedImage2 <T, warpedImage2, warpedResImg)`

Comment: Please post the original images: 1) The first of the images in the stitch. 2) The second of the images in the stitch. 3) The stitched image without the red markings.

Comment: @AnnZen I can not add original-sized images as they are big in size. I have resized it and added in question. pls check

Comment: You might want to use this method: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/393/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because when you do the warping, the border pixels of the image get resampled/interpolated with black background pixels. This leaves a non-zero border around your warped image of varying values that show as your dashed dark line when merged with the other image. This happens because your merge test is binary, tested with != 0.

So one simple thing you can do is mask the warped image in Python/OpenCV to get its bounds from the black background outside the image and then erode the mask. Then use the mask to erode the image boundary.  This can be achieve by the following changes to your last lines of code presented as follows:

```
if A is None:
    fullTransformation = np.dot(translation,H) #again, images must be translated to be 100% visible in new canvas
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, fullTransformation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))

else:
    warpedImageTemp = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpAffine(warpedImageTemp, A, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    mask2 = cv2.threshold(warpedImage2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
    mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
    warpedImage2[mask2==0] = 0

result = np.where(warpedImage2 != 0, warpedImage2, warpedResImg)
```

I simply added the following code lines to your code:

```
mask2 = cv2.threshold(warpedImage2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
warpedImage2[mask2==0] = 0
```

You can increase the kernel size if desired to erode more.

Here is the before and after. Note that I did not have SURF and tried to use ORB, which did not align well. So your roads do not align. But the mismatch due to misalignment emphasizes the issue as it shows the dashed jagged black border line. The fact that ORB did not work or I do not have proper code from above to make it align is not important. The masking does what I think you want and is extendable to the processing of all your images.

[image]

The other thing that can be done in combination with the above is to feather the mask and then ramp blend the two images using the mask. This is done by blurring the mask (a bit more) and then stretching the values over the inside half of the blurred border and making the ramp only on the outside half of the blurred border. Then blend the two images with the ramped mask and its inverse as follows for the same code as above.

```
    if A is None:
        fullTransformation = np.dot(translation,H) #again, images must be translated to be 100% visible in new canvas
        warpedImage2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, fullTransformation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    
    else:
        warpedImageTemp = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
        warpedImage2 = cv2.warpAffine(warpedImageTemp, A, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
        mask2 = cv2.threshold(warpedImage2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
        mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
        warpedImage2[mask2==0] = 0
        mask2 = cv2.blur(mask2, (5,5))
        mask2 = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask2, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.float64)
    
    result = (warpedImage2 * mask2 +  warpedResImg * (255 - mask2))/255
    result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("image1_image2_merged3.png", result)
```

The result when compared to the original composite is as follows:

[image]

**ADDITION**

I have corrected my ORB code to reverse the use of images and now it aligns. So here are all 3 techniques: the original, the one that only uses a binary mask and the one that uses a ramped mask for blending (all as described above).

[image]

**ADDITION2**

Here are the 3 requested images: original, binary masked, ramped mask blending.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here is my ORB code for the last version above**

I tried to change as little as possible from your code, except I had to use ORB and I had to swap the names image1 and image2 near the end.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity


image1 = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
image2 = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")

gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
MAX_FEATURES = 500
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15
orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)

keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray1, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray2, None)

# Match features.
matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)

# Sort matches by score
matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

# Remove not so good matches
numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

# Draw top matches
imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(image1, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2, matches, None)
cv2.imwrite("/Users/fred/desktop/image1_image2_matches.png", imMatches)

# Extract location of good matches
points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
    points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

print(points1)
print("")
print(points2)

A = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(points1,points2,fullAffine=False)
#print(A)

if A is None:
    HomogResult = cv2.findHomography(points1,points2,method=cv2.RANSAC)
    H = HomogResult[0]

height1,width1 = image1.shape[:2]
height2,width2 = image2.shape[:2]

corners1 = np.float32(([0,0],[0,height1],[width1,height1],[width1,0]))
corners2 = np.float32(([0,0],[0,height2],[width2,height2],[width2,0]))

warpedCorners2 = np.zeros((4,2))

# project corners2 into domain of image1 from A affine or H homography
for i in range(0,4):
    cornerX = corners2[i,0]
    cornerY = corners2[i,1]
    if A is not None: #check if we're working with affine transform or perspective transform
        warpedCorners2[i,0] = A[0,0]*cornerX + A[0,1]*cornerY + A[0,2]
        warpedCorners2[i,1] = A[1,0]*cornerX + A[1,1]*cornerY + A[1,2]
    else:
        warpedCorners2[i,0] = (H[0,0]*cornerX + H[0,1]*cornerY + H[0,2])/(H[2,0]*cornerX + H[2,1]*cornerY + H[2,2])
        warpedCorners2[i,1] = (H[1,0]*cornerX + H[1,1]*cornerY + H[1,2])/(H[2,0]*cornerX + H[2,1]*cornerY + H[2,2])

allCorners = np.concatenate((corners1, warpedCorners2), axis=0)

[xMin, yMin] = np.int32(allCorners.min(axis=0).ravel() - 0.5)
[xMax, yMax] = np.int32(allCorners.max(axis=0).ravel() + 0.5)

translation = np.float32(([1,0,-1*xMin],[0,1,-1*yMin],[0,0,1]))
warpedResImg = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))


if A is None:
    fullTransformation = np.dot(translation,H) #again, images must be translated to be 100% visible in new canvas
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, fullTransformation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))

else:
    warpedImageTemp = cv2.warpPerspective(image1, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpAffine(warpedImageTemp, A, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    mask2 = cv2.threshold(warpedImage2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
    mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
    warpedImage2[mask2==0] = 0
    mask2 = cv2.blur(mask2, (5,5))
    mask2 = rescale_intensity(mask2, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.float64)

result = (warpedImage2 * mask2 +  warpedResImg * (255 - mask2))/255
result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("image1_image2_merged2.png", result)
```

You had the following. Note where the names, image1 and image2 are being used compared to my code above.

```
warpedResImg = cv2.warpPerspective(image1, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))


if A is None:
    fullTransformation = np.dot(translation,H) #again, images must be translated to be 100% visible in new canvas
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, fullTransformation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))

else:
    warpedImageTemp = cv2.warpPerspective(image2, translation, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
    warpedImage2 = cv2.warpAffine(warpedImageTemp, A, (xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin))
```

Comment: Could you post a non gif version of the final result picture so one can compare without getting a headache?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code. Now there is no black line but I am getting slight misalignment and stitched edge effect as updated in my question. Is it because you are using ORB and I am using SURF? I tried ORB but its giving me less than 10 matching points so not stitching images. How I can improve that? I have used your code part but not getting result like yours.

Comment: There could be differences due to the use of ORB. SURF or SIFT should be fine if properly set up. My additional code is independent of those techniques. It just blends and does not do any geometry adjustment other than a slight removal of a row of dark pixels around the outside of the images before blending. As I do not have SURF installed, I cannot test your code right now. Something was odd about the code you posted as I had to swap image1 and image2 at the end to get them to align as I mentioned. Why was that? Does your code actually work for the example above?

Comment: @fmw42 I used your code and changed that part in my code( if else part). So the black line was removed but ramped mask blending which is mentioned in your ADDITION2 is not getting in my result as shown in question update. If you could please provide your whole code then I can check what is the difference. I am executing code for multiple images. What is mean by setting SURF/SIFT properly? Also if you could please provide where I can learn these techniques references that will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: where you swaped images? if you could comment in your code what is that doing that will be easy to understand. Sorry as I am new to this and learning things so I am getting so many questions and these terms, techniques are not easily understanding.

Comment: I will post my corrected code. If I run your code, the images do not align. I did not analyze your code to understand all what you did. I simple swapped the use of the names image1 and image2 in two places. Your code gave the results at the top of my answer that do not align at all. After swapping the names, I got the code to align.

Comment: @fmw42:Hi! I came across this post. Do you think you can help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878901/image-reconstruction-from-predicted-array-normalize-unnormalize-array)?

Comment: @George Sorry, I know nothing about tensor flow and CNN models.

Answer (score 0):

### Horizontal Gluing

I will focus on one of the cuts as a prove of concept. I agree with the comments that your code is a bit lengthy and hard to work with. So step one is to glue the pictures myself.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

upper_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('yQv6W.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)/255
lower_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('zoWJv.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)/255

result_image = np.zeros((466+139,700+22,3))
result_image[139:139+lower_image.shape[0],:lower_image.shape[1]] = lower_image
result_image[0:upper_image.shape[0], 22:22+upper_image.shape[1]] = upper_image
plt.imshow(result_image)
```

[image: naive glue]

Ok no dashed black line but I admit not perfect either. So the next step is to align at least the street and the little way at the very right of the picture. For that I will need to shrink the picture to non integer size and turn that back into a grid. I will use a `knn` like method for that.

**Edit:** As requested in the comments I'll explain the shrinking a bit more detailed since it would have to be done by hand again for an other stitching. The magic happens in the line (I replaced n by it's value)

```
f = UnivariateSpline([0,290,510,685],[0,310,530,700])
```

I tried first to scale the lower picture in the x-direction to make the little way on the very right fit the upper image. Unfortunately then the street wouldn't fit the street. So what I do is scale down according to the above function. At pixel 0 I still want to have pixel zero, at 290 I want to have what used to be at 310 and so on.
Notice that 290,510 and 310,530 are the new respectively old x-coordinates of street and way at the hight of the gluing.

```
class Image_knn():
    def fit(self, image):
        self.image = image.astype('float')

    def predict(self, x, y):
        image = self.image
        weights_x = [(1-(x % 1)).reshape(*x.shape,1), (x % 1).reshape(*x.shape,1)]
        weights_y = [(1-(y % 1)).reshape(*x.shape,1), (y % 1).reshape(*x.shape,1)]
        start_x = np.floor(x).astype('int')
        start_y = np.floor(y).astype('int')
        return sum([image[np.clip(np.floor(start_x + x), 0, image.shape[0]-1).astype('int'),
                          np.clip(np.floor(start_y + y), 0, image.shape[1]-1).astype('int')] * weights_x[x]*weights_y[y] 
                    for x,y in itertools.product(range(2),range(2))])

image_model = Image_knn()
image_model.fit(lower_image)

n = 685
f = UnivariateSpline([0,290,510,n],[0,310,530,700])
np.linspace(0,lower_image.shape[1],n)
yspace = f(np.arange(n))

result_image = np.zeros((466+139,700+22, 3))
a,b = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,lower_image.shape[0]), yspace)
result_image[139:139+lower_image.shape[0],:n] = np.transpose(image_model.predict(a,b), [1,0,2])
result_image[0:upper_image.shape[0], 22:22+upper_image.shape[1]] = upper_image
plt.imshow(result_image, 'gray')
```

[image: gluing with alignment]

Much better, no black line but maybe we can still smoothen the cut a bit. I figured if I take convex combinations of upper and lower image at the cut it would look much better.

```
result_image = np.zeros((466+139,700+22,3))
a,b = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,lower_image.shape[0]), yspace)
result_image[139:139+lower_image.shape[0],:n] = np.transpose(image_model.predict(a,b), [1,0,2])

transition_range = 10
result_image[0:upper_image.shape[0]-transition_range, 22:22+upper_image.shape[1]] = upper_image[:-transition_range,:]
transition_pixcels = upper_image[-transition_range:,:]*np.linspace(1,0,transition_range).reshape(-1,1,1)
result_image[upper_image.shape[0]-transition_range:upper_image.shape[0], 22:22+upper_image.shape[1]] *= np.linspace(0,1,transition_range).reshape(-1,1,1)
result_image[upper_image.shape[0]-transition_range:upper_image.shape[0], 22:22+upper_image.shape[1]] += transition_pixcels
plt.imshow(result_image)
plt.savefig('text.jpg')
```

[image: Final Gluing]

### Tilted Gluing

For completeness here also a version gluing at the top with a tilted bottom. I attach the pictures at a point and turn around that `fixed point` by a few degrees. And again I am correcting some very slight non alignements in the end. To get the coordinates of that I am using jupyter lab and `%matplotlib widget`.

```
fixed_point_upper = np.array([139,379])
fixed_point_lower = np.array([0,400])
angle = np.deg2rad(2)
down_dir = np.array([np.sin(angle+np.pi/2),np.cos(angle+np.pi/2)])
right_dir = np.array([np.sin(angle),np.cos(angle)])

result_image_height = np.ceil((fixed_point_upper+lower_image.shape[0]*down_dir+(lower_image.shape[1]-fixed_point_lower[1])*right_dir)[0]).astype('int')
right_shift = np.ceil(-(fixed_point_upper+lower_image.shape[0]*down_dir-fixed_point_lower[1]*right_dir)[1]).astype('int')
result_image_width = right_shift+upper_image.shape[1]
result_image = np.zeros([result_image_height, result_image_width,3])
fixed_point_result = np.array([fixed_point_upper[0],fixed_point_upper[1]+right_shift])

lower_top_left = fixed_point_result-fixed_point_lower[1]*right_dir
result_image[:upper_image.shape[0],-upper_image.shape[1]:] = upper_image

# calculate points in lower_image
result_coordinates = np.stack(np.where(np.ones(result_image.shape[:2],dtype='bool')),axis=1)
lower_coordinates = np.stack([(result_coordinates-lower_top_left)@down_dir,(result_coordinates-lower_top_left)@right_dir],axis=1)
mask = (0 <= lower_coordinates[:,0]) & (0 <= lower_coordinates[:,1]) \
    & (lower_coordinates[:,0] <= lower_image.shape[0]) & (lower_coordinates[:,1] <= lower_image.shape[1])
result_coordinates = result_coordinates[mask]
lower_coordinates = lower_coordinates[mask]

# COORDINATES ON RESULT IMAGE
# left street 254
# left sides of houses 295, 420, 505
# right small street, both sides big street 590,635,664

# COORDINATES ON LOWER IMAGE
# left street 234
# left sides of houses 280, 399, 486
# right small street, both sides big street 571, 617, 642

def coord_transform(y): 
    return (y-lower_top_left[1])/right_dir[1]
y = tuple(map(coord_transform, [lower_top_left[1], 254, 295, 420, 505, 589, 635, 664]))
f = UnivariateSpline(y,[0, 234, 280, 399, 486, 571, 617, 642])
result_image[result_coordinates[:,0],result_coordinates[:,1]] = image_model.predict(lower_coordinates[:,0],np.vectorize(f)(lower_coordinates[:,1]))
```

[image: Tilted Gluing]

Comment: Smoothing over a cut is valid but easier when you have the cut as horizontal. Can you do that when you have an irregular curve for the cut that is at an angle and not a straight line after you have warped one or both images. That is what is hard. When you try to merge at the extremes of the image if they do not overlap or even when they overlap. That is not a trivial process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Result stitching is good but can we get original color of images? And will this code work for multiple image stitching?

Comment: Here I am giving result of two images. In fact I am stitching multiple images having high resolution. What integer values you are using in your code lets say at time of stitching, will that be same for stitching with other inputs also?

Comment: @fmw42 I think it should be possible. If you open a new question, provide the pictures and matching curves in both pictures I am willing to try.

Comment: @ganesh I think the colors should be no problem. You would need to adopt my `Image_knn` to work with 3d images or use it 3 times once for each color.

Comment: @ganesh There are two parts where I worked out some integers by hand. That you would have to do again for a different stitching. First it that the pictures approximately fit together if you glue the lower 22 pixels to the left and 139 pixels below. You see the result of just gluing like that in the first picture. The 2nd is where I shrinked the lower picture very slightly to make the street and the little way at the very right agree in both pictures. I will edit my question to explain that better since it does not fit here.

Comment: Will above code work for multiple images? I am looking for solution which will work for multiple image stitching.

Comment: @ganesh I added colors and tried to explain better what you have have to do by hand to make the same happen for different images. Do you have further questions?

Comment: @ganesh Oh and I don't see why it shouldn't work for multiple ones.