# How to get rid of black lines caused of blending images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, blending

I recently worked on a project that required blending multiple images together. I successfully completed all the necessary steps and successfully blended the images. However, I noticed that when I blended the images, black lines appeared on the borders of each piece of the final image, indicating where each image was placed. You can see an example of the final image with these artifacts in the following link:

[final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQBg8.jpg)

These artifacts are noticeable even with a quick glance at the image.

This is my code for blending the images:

```
def normalize_piece(img):
    return cv2.normalize(img.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)


def blend_pieces(piece1, piece2, transformation_matrix, width, height):
    piece1_norm = normalize_piece(piece1)
    piece2_norm = normalize_piece(piece2)

    piece1_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(src=piece1_norm, M=transformation_matrix, dsize=(width, height))

    black_rgb_pixel = np.zeros(3)
    mask_left = np.all(piece1_warped != black_rgb_pixel, axis=-1)
    mask_right = np.all(piece2_norm != black_rgb_pixel, axis=-1)

    mask_overlap = mask_left & mask_right
    mask_left_only = mask_left & ~mask_right
    mask_right_only = mask_right & ~mask_left

    piece1_warped[mask_left_only] = piece1_warped[mask_left_only]
    piece1_warped[mask_right_only] = piece2_norm[mask_right_only]
    piece1_warped[mask_overlap] = (piece1_warped[mask_overlap] + piece2_norm[mask_overlap]) / 2

    return piece1_warped
```

## Edit

I have these 3 parts of the final image for example and I want to merge them together:

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0O9A.jpg), [part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4lW3.jpg), [part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qii16.jpg)

I need to blend part 1 with part 2. And then, I need to blend the blended part with part 3.

Comment: I have an idea of taking the final image and cleaning the black lines which are artifacts. However, there are 2 problems with this approach. First, the background is black. Second, there are black parts in the resulting image (like the jacket in the above example). These problems lead to that that I can't make a mask/filter which uses threshold.

Comment: Your mask is too loose, make it a little smaller, for example with an erosion. One slick trick to make the mask is to warp an image with all 1s. The resulting warped mask will have values in between 0 and 1 at the edges, which you can use to blend. You can also implement more complex merging schemes, such as this: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/393/

Comment: You can post-process the result by interpolating.
1. Create a mask of the black artifacted lines
2. Use e.g. [Nearest Interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html)

Comment: the trick mentioned by Cris can be wrapped into the warp itself in one single step if the source image has a 4th channel containing all ones.

Comment: I tried the things you guys said but I didn't get the results that I desire so I added 3 images to the question maybe someone could demonstrate a Python code on these 3 images and blend them together without having these black artifacts. Thank you.

Comment: what Cris suggested is to _generate_ the mask _using_ the warp. *already*-warped images can't be used for this. how about you try this: extend your source image, give it a 4th channel, set it to all-255. then generate your three warped images from that 4-channel image. save the images. they will appear 'transparent" but transparency is not really the point. that channel is now a mask that can be eroded so you only get completely valid pixels, not edge pixels.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565531/remove-black-dashed-lines-from-image-stitching/68641183#68641183

Comment: @fmw42 The code you provided is expired and sadly has a lot of errors, I tried to fix these errors and I was able to do so but still the final result had deformed colorful lines on the edge of the parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve an answer to my question.

Here is a simple code to merge the parts that were provided in the question:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

width = 808
height = 457


def blend_images(image1, image2):
    # Create the canvas with the desired shape
    # Note that when debugging it shows that the canvas is ndarray of shape (457, 808, 3)
    # The 457 here represents the height, the 808 represents the width and the 3 represents the channels (RGB)
    canvas = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Iterate over the canvas and the two images while taking the maximum RGB value of the two images for each pixel
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            canvas[y, x] = np.maximum(image1[y, x], image2[y, x])

    return canvas


def main():
    # Change the images paths to your images paths
    image1 = cv2.imread('part1.jpg')
    image2 = cv2.imread('part2.jpg')
    image3 = cv2.imread('part3.jpg')

    # Blend the first two images
    canvas1 = blend_images(image1, image2)

    # Blend the blended images with the third image to get the final result
    canvas2 = blend_images(canvas1, image3)

    # Show the final result
    cv2.imshow('Canvas', canvas2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `blend_images` function creates a canvas of the specified shape (height, width) and merges the two input images using an element-wise maximum operation. Specifically, the function iterates over each pixel of the canvas and selects the maximum RGB value from the corresponding pixels in the two input images. The resulting pixel values are then assigned to the corresponding pixel in the new image.

## Update

Thanks to a helpful comment from 'Christoph Rackwitz', it was pointed out that the merging operation in the `blend_images` function can be performed more efficiently using a Numpy routine.

**Here's an updated version of the code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def blend_images(image1, image2):
    # Ensure that the input images have the same shape
    assert image1.shape == image2.shape
    return np.maximum(image1, image2)


def main():
    # Change the images paths to your images paths
    image1 = cv2.imread('part1.jpg')
    image2 = cv2.imread('part2.jpg')
    image3 = cv2.imread('part3.jpg')

    # Blend the first two images
    canvas = blend_images(image1, image2)

    # Blend the blended images with the third image to get the final result
    canvas = blend_images(canvas, image3)

    # Show the final result
    cv2.imshow('Canvas', canvas)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this updated code, the `blend_images` function is modified to use the Numpy `maximum` function instead of nested loops to perform the merging operation. The function also includes an assertion to ensure that the input images have the same shape.

Comment: that double loop will be extremely slow. just use numpy routines to apply this to whole arrays at a time. also be aware that this operates per-channel, so the maximum of red and green is yellow. that isn't actually blending, i.e. not a linear combination of two images.