# image reconstruction from predicted array - padding same shows grid tiles in reconstructed image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

I have two images, `E1` and `E3`, and I am training a CNN model.

In order to train the model, I use `E1` as train and `E3` as y_train.

I extract tiles from these images in order to train the model on tiles.

The model, does not have an activation layer, so the output can take any value.

So, the predictions for example, `preds` , have values around `preds.max() = 2.35` and `preds.min() = -1.77`.

My problem is that I can't reconstruct the image at the end using `preds` and I think the problem is the scaling-unscaling of the `preds` values.

If I just do `np.uint8(preds)` its is almost full of zeros since `preds` has small values.

The image should look like as close as possible to `E2` image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, \
    Input, Add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from PIL import Image

CHANNELS = 1
HEIGHT = 32
WIDTH = 32
INIT_SIZE = ((1429, 1416))

def NormalizeData(data):
    return (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data) + 1e-6)

def extract_image_tiles(size, im):
    im = im[:, :, :CHANNELS]
    w = h = size
    idxs = [(i, (i + h), j, (j + w)) for i in range(0, im.shape[0], h) for j in range(0, im.shape[1], w)]
    tiles_asarrays = []
    count = 0
    for k, (i_start, i_end, j_start, j_end) in enumerate(idxs):
        tile = im[i_start:i_end, j_start:j_end, ...]
        if tile.shape[:2] != (h, w):
            tile_ = tile
            tile_size = (h, w) if tile.ndim == 2 else (h, w, tile.shape[2])
            tile = np.zeros(tile_size, dtype=tile.dtype)
            tile[:tile_.shape[0], :tile_.shape[1], ...] = tile_
        
        count += 1
        tiles_asarrays.append(tile)
    return np.array(idxs), np.array(tiles_asarrays)


def build_model(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))

    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)
    
    f3 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f2)
    f3 = BatchNormalization()(f3)
    f3 = Activation('relu')(f3)

    addition = Add()([f2, f3])
    
    f4 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(addition)
    
    f5 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f4)
    f5 = BatchNormalization()(f5)
    f5 = Activation('relu')(f5)
   
    f6 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f5)
    f6 = BatchNormalization()(f6)
    f6 = Activation('relu')(f6)
   
    output = Conv2D(1, 1, padding='same')(f6)

    model = Model(inputs, output)

    return model

# Load data
img = cv2.imread('E1.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = cv2.resize(img, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = np.array(img, np.uint8)
#plt.imshow(img)
img3 = cv2.imread('E3.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img3 = cv2.resize(img3, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img3 = np.array(img3, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
idxs, tiles = extract_image_tiles(WIDTH, img)
idxs2, tiles3 = extract_image_tiles(WIDTH, img3)

# split to train and test data
split_idx = int(tiles.shape[0] * 0.9)

train = tiles[:split_idx]
val = tiles[split_idx:]

y_train = tiles3[:split_idx]
y_val = tiles3[split_idx:]

# build model
model = build_model(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss = tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name='rmse')])

# scale data before training
train  = train / 255.
val = val / 255.

y_train = y_train / 255.
y_val = y_val / 255.

# train
history = model.fit(train, 
                    y_train, 
                    validation_data=(val, y_val),
                    epochs=50)

# predict on E2
img2 = cv2.imread('E2.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = np.array(img2, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
idxs, tiles2 = extract_image_tiles(WIDTH, img2)

#scale data
tiles2 = tiles2 / 255.

preds = model.predict(tiles2)
#preds = NormalizeData(preds)
#preds = np.uint8(preds)
# reconstruct predictions
reconstructed = np.zeros((img.shape[0],
                          img.shape[1]),
                          dtype=np.uint8)

# reconstruction process
for tile, (y_start, y_end, x_start, x_end) in zip(preds[:, :, -1], idxs):
    y_end = min(y_end, img.shape[0])
    x_end = min(x_end, img.shape[1])
    reconstructed[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end] = tile[:(y_end - y_start), :(x_end - x_start)]


im = Image.fromarray(reconstructed)
im = im.resize(INIT_SIZE)
im.show()
```

You can find the data [here](https://easyupload.io/m/3y2rl8)

If I use :

```
def normalize_arr_to_uint8(arr):
  the_min = arr.min()
  the_max = arr.max()
  the_max -= the_min
  arr = ((arr - the_min) / the_max) * 255.
  return arr.astype(np.uint8)


preds = model.predict(tiles2)
preds = normalize_arr_to_uint8(preds)
```

then, I receive an image which seems right, but with lines all over.

Here is the image I get:

[image]

This is the image I should take (as close as possible to `E2`). Note, that I just use a small cnn network for this example, so I can't receive receive much details for the image. But, when I try better model, still I have horizontal and/or vertical lines:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found this.

In the code above, I use at:

```
# reconstruction process
for tile, (y_start, y_end, x_start, x_end) in zip(preds[:, :, -1], idxs):
```

`preds[:, :, -1]` this is wrong.

I must use `preds[:, :, :, -1]` because `preds` shape is: `(1936, 32, 32, 1)`.

So, If I use `preds[:, :, -1]` I am receiving the image I posted.

If I use `preds[:, :, :, -1]`, which is right , I receive a new image where except from the horizontal lines, I get vertical lines also!

[image: the new image]

**UPDATE 2**

I am just adding new code where I use another patches and reconstruction functions, but produce the same results (a little better picture).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, \
    Input, Add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from PIL import Image

# gpu setup
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    
CHANNELS = 1
HEIGHT = 1408
WIDTH = 1408
PATCH_SIZE = 32
STRIDE = PATCH_SIZE//2
INIT_SIZE = ((1429, 1416))

def normalize_arr_to_uint8(arr):
  the_min = arr.min()
  the_max = arr.max()
  the_max -= the_min
  arr = ((arr - the_min) / the_max) * 255.
  return arr.astype(np.uint8)


def NormalizeData(data):
    return (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data) + 1e-6)


def recon_im(patches: np.ndarray, im_h: int, im_w: int, n_channels: int, stride: int):
    """Reconstruct the image from all patches.
        Patches are assumed to be square and overlapping depending on the stride. The image is constructed
         by filling in the patches from left to right, top to bottom, averaging the overlapping parts.

    Parameters
    -----------
    patches: 4D ndarray with shape (patch_number,patch_height,patch_width,channels)
        Array containing extracted patches. If the patches contain colour information,
        channels are indexed along the last dimension: RGB patches would
        have `n_channels=3`.
    im_h: int
        original height of image to be reconstructed
    im_w: int
        original width of image to be reconstructed
    n_channels: int
        number of channels the image has. For  RGB image, n_channels = 3
    stride: int
           desired patch stride

    Returns
    -----------
    reconstructedim: ndarray with shape (height, width, channels)
                      or ndarray with shape (height, width) if output image only has one channel
                    Reconstructed image from the given patches
    """

    patch_size = patches.shape[1]  # patches assumed to be square

    # Assign output image shape based on patch sizes
    rows = ((im_h - patch_size) // stride) * stride + patch_size
    cols = ((im_w - patch_size) // stride) * stride + patch_size

    if n_channels == 1:
        reconim = np.zeros((rows, cols))
        divim = np.zeros((rows, cols))
    else:
        reconim = np.zeros((rows, cols, n_channels))
        divim = np.zeros((rows, cols, n_channels))

    p_c = (cols - patch_size + stride) / stride  # number of patches needed to fill out a row

    totpatches = patches.shape[0]
    initr, initc = 0, 0

    # extract each patch and place in the zero matrix and sum it with existing pixel values

    reconim[initr:patch_size, initc:patch_size] = patches[0]# fill out top left corner using first patch
    divim[initr:patch_size, initc:patch_size] = np.ones(patches[0].shape)

    patch_num = 1

    while patch_num <= totpatches - 1:
        initc = initc + stride
        reconim[initr:initr + patch_size, initc:patch_size + initc] += patches[patch_num]
        divim[initr:initr + patch_size, initc:patch_size + initc] += np.ones(patches[patch_num].shape)

        if np.remainder(patch_num + 1, p_c) == 0 and patch_num < totpatches - 1:
            initr = initr + stride
            initc = 0
            reconim[initr:initr + patch_size, initc:patch_size] += patches[patch_num + 1]
            divim[initr:initr + patch_size, initc:patch_size] += np.ones(patches[patch_num].shape)
            patch_num += 1
        patch_num += 1
    # Average out pixel values
    reconstructedim = reconim / divim

    return reconstructedim


def get_patches(GT, stride, patch_size):
    """Extracts square patches from an image of any size.
    Parameters
    -----------
    GT : ndarray
        n-dimensional array containing the image from which patches are to be extracted
    stride : int
           desired patch stride
    patch_size : int
               patch size
    Returns
    -----------
    patches: ndarray
            array containing all patches
    im_h: int
        height of image to be reconstructed
    im_w: int
        width of image to be reconstructed
    n_channels: int
        number of channels the image has. For  RGB image, n_channels = 3
    """

    hr_patches = []

    for i in range(0, GT.shape[0] - patch_size + 1, stride):
        for j in range(0, GT.shape[1] - patch_size + 1, stride):
            hr_patches.append(GT[i:i + patch_size, j:j + patch_size])

    im_h, im_w = GT.shape[0], GT.shape[1]

    if len(GT.shape) == 2:
        n_channels = 1
    else:
        n_channels = GT.shape[2]

    patches = np.asarray(hr_patches)

    return patches, im_h, im_w, n_channels


def build_model(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))

    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)
    
    f3 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f2)
    f3 = BatchNormalization()(f3)
    f3 = Activation('relu')(f3)

    addition = Add()([f2, f3])
    
    f4 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(addition)
    
    f5 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f4)
    f5 = BatchNormalization()(f5)
    f5 = Activation('relu')(f5)
   
    f6 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f5)
    f6 = BatchNormalization()(f6)
    f6 = Activation('relu')(f6)
   
    output = Conv2D(1, 1, padding='same')(f6)

    model = Model(inputs, output)

    return model

# Load data
img = cv2.imread('E1.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = cv2.resize(img, (HEIGHT, WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = np.array(img, np.uint8)

img3 = cv2.imread('E3.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img3 = cv2.resize(img3, (HEIGHT, WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img3 = np.array(img3, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
tiles, H, W, C = get_patches(img[:, :, :CHANNELS], stride=STRIDE, patch_size=PATCH_SIZE)
tiles3, H, W, C = get_patches(img3[:, :, :CHANNELS], stride=STRIDE, patch_size=PATCH_SIZE)


# split to train and test data
split_idx = int(tiles.shape[0] * 0.9)

train = tiles[:split_idx]
val = tiles[split_idx:]

y_train = tiles3[:split_idx]
y_val = tiles3[split_idx:]

# build model
model = build_model(PATCH_SIZE, PATCH_SIZE, CHANNELS)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss = tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name='rmse')])

# scale data before training
train  = train / 255.
val = val / 255.

y_train = y_train / 255.
y_val = y_val / 255.

# train
history = model.fit(train, 
                    y_train, 
                    validation_data=(val, y_val),
                    batch_size=16,
                    epochs=20)

# predict on E2
img2 = cv2.imread('E2.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (HEIGHT, WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = np.array(img2, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
tiles2, H, W, CHANNELS = get_patches(img2[:, :, :CHANNELS], stride=STRIDE, patch_size=PATCH_SIZE)

#scale data
tiles2 = tiles2 / 255.


preds = model.predict(tiles2)
preds = normalize_arr_to_uint8(preds)

reconstructed = recon_im(preds[:, :, :, -1], HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS, stride=STRIDE)

im = Image.fromarray(reconstructed)
im = im.resize(INIT_SIZE)
im.show()
```

and the image produced:

[image: stride16]

**UPDATE 3**

After @Lescurel comment, I tried this arcitecture:

```
def build_model(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))

    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='valid')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
 
    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, strides=2,padding='valid')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)
    
    f3 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f2)
    f3 = BatchNormalization()(f3)
    f3 = Activation('relu')(f3)

    addition = Add()([f2, f3])
    
    f4 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='valid')(addition)
    
    f5 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='valid')(f4)
    f5 = BatchNormalization()(f5)
    f5 = Activation('relu')(f5)
   
    f6 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='valid')(f5)
    f6 = BatchNormalization()(f6)
    f6 = Activation('relu')(f6)
   
    f7 = Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, strides=2,padding='same')(f6)
    f7 = BatchNormalization()(f7)
    f7 = Activation('relu')(f7)
    
    f8 = Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, strides=2,padding='same')(f7)
    f8 = BatchNormalization()(f8)
    f8 = Activation('relu')(f8)
    
    output = Conv2D(1,1, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(f8)

    model = Model(inputs, output)

    return model
```

which uses valid and same padding and the image I receive its:

So, the square tiles changed dimensions and shape.

So, the problem is how can I use my original architecture and get rid of these tiles!

[image: padding]

Comment: can you show the images you get?

Comment: Is this model used for denoising ?

Comment: @anarchy:It is used for upscaling. I am updating in a few minutes the post.

Comment: Why not just use sigmoid as the last operation of your function? It will save you this  hassle with postprocessing, and likely also speed up model convergence.

Comment: @simeonovich:HI, I already tried that but still I can see the square tile border lines.So, the problem must be in the reconstruction of the image.

Comment: The padding "same" in your convolution is padding the images with 0, wihch will probably introduce some tiling artifacts when reconstructing the whole image. Did you try to overlap your patches and only use the middle of each patch?

Comment: @Lescurel:Hmm..That's a point. When you say use the middle of each patch?? How to do that? And leave `padding=same`?

Comment: Now, I didn't mean to touch your model architecture, I meant to modify your `get_patch` function to generate overlapping patches. You can then discard sides to keep only the data from the center of each predicted patch. You'll have to adjust the reconstruction as well.

Comment: Don't want to interrupt your discussion here, but that (using the center crop of overlapping tiles) is exactly what my answer is proposing plus some smoothing / filtering for post-processing. @Lescurel is right, your issue is about tiling artifacts. A known problem in stitching images. I think this one here is solved with the code below. Thanks for the nice task.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77955629/apply-formulas-to-remove-artifacts-from-reconstuction-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Now that I understood this:**

> My problem is not the small black box. This is some bad pixel. My
> problem is the square tile border lines.

This is a stitching problem in my opinion. The border lines, come from your approach to crop the full image into tiles and then stitch them back together later. **Due to the padding of your convolutions in your model architecture, it is expected to have border artifacts**.

There are two things you can do now:

> 1. Train and process on larger tiles and then crop the center tile. This does away with the padding issue by "cutting away the problematic
>    parts"

```
def extract_image_tiles_with_overlap(size, stride, im, center_tile_width, overlap_percentage):

    im = im[:, :, :CHANNELS]
    w = h = size
    s = stride
    overlap = int(center_tile_width * overlap_percentage / 100)

    idxs = [(i, (i + h), j, (j + w)) for i in range(0, im.shape[0] - h + 1, s) for j in
            range(0, im.shape[1] - w + 1, s)]
    tiles_asarrays = []

    for k, (i_start, i_end, j_start, j_end) in enumerate(idxs):
        tile = im[i_start:i_end, j_start:j_end, ...]

        if tile.shape[:2] != (h, w):
            tile_ = tile
            tile_size = (h, w) if tile.ndim == 2 else (h, w, tile.shape[2])
            tile = np.zeros(tile_size, dtype=tile.dtype)
            tile[:tile_.shape[0], :tile_.shape[1], ...] = tile_

        tiles_asarrays.append(tile)

    return np.array(idxs), np.array(tiles_asarrays), overlap
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Of course this does not completely solve the stitching problem entirely. As a next step you can experiment with aggregating overlapping segments of the tiles to get this smoother.

> 2. This smoothing through aggregation can also be done as a post-processing step. E.g. via a Gaussian Filtering, or morphological operations.

```
iterations = 10  # Adjust the number of iterations as needed
reconstructed_dilated = binary_dilation(reconstructed, iterations=iterations)
reconstructed_smoothed = binary_erosion(reconstructed_dilated, iterations=iterations)
```

Or you use some OpenCV denoising (make sure to further optimize the hyperparameters).

```
denoised_reconstructed = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(reconstructed, h=10, templateWindowSize=7, searchWindowSize=21)
```

Result now is this:

[image]

Full code to reproduce I changed a few other things (e.g. model saving, etc.)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, \
    Input, Add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from PIL import Image
import os
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation, binary_erosion



CHANNELS = 1
HEIGHT = 32
WIDTH = 32
INIT_SIZE = ((1429, 1416))
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = 'my_croptile_model.h5'  # Change this path to your desired location



def NormalizeData(data):
    return (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data) + 1e-6)

def extract_image_tiles_with_overlap(size, stride, im, center_tile_width, overlap_percentage):
    im = im[:, :, :CHANNELS]
    w = h = size
    s = stride
    overlap = int(center_tile_width * overlap_percentage / 100)

    idxs = [(i, (i + h), j, (j + w)) for i in range(0, im.shape[0] - h + 1, s) for j in
            range(0, im.shape[1] - w + 1, s)]
    tiles_asarrays = []

    for k, (i_start, i_end, j_start, j_end) in enumerate(idxs):
        tile = im[i_start:i_end, j_start:j_end, ...]

        if tile.shape[:2] != (h, w):
            tile_ = tile
            tile_size = (h, w) if tile.ndim == 2 else (h, w, tile.shape[2])
            tile = np.zeros(tile_size, dtype=tile.dtype)
            tile[:tile_.shape[0], :tile_.shape[1], ...] = tile_

        tiles_asarrays.append(tile)

    return np.array(idxs), np.array(tiles_asarrays), overlap

def build_model(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))

    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)

    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)

    f3 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f2)
    f3 = BatchNormalization()(f3)
    f3 = Activation('relu')(f3)

    addition = Add()([f2, f3])

    f4 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(addition)

    f5 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f4)
    f5 = BatchNormalization()(f5)
    f5 = Activation('relu')(f5)

    f6 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f5)
    f6 = BatchNormalization()(f6)
    f6 = Activation('relu')(f6)

    output = Conv2D(1, 1, padding='same')(f6)

    model = Model(inputs, output)

    return model


# Load data
img = cv2.imread('images/E1.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = cv2.resize(img, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = np.array(img, np.uint8)
# plt.imshow(img)
img3 = cv2.imread('images/E3.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img3 = cv2.resize(img3, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img3 = np.array(img3, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
# idxs, tiles = extract_image_tiles(WIDTH, img)
# idxs2, tiles3 = extract_image_tiles(WIDTH, img3)

# extract tiles from images with overlap
center_tile_width = WIDTH  # Adjust as needed
overlap_percentage = 60  # Adjust as needed
idxs, tiles, overlap = extract_image_tiles_with_overlap(WIDTH, WIDTH // 2, img, center_tile_width, overlap_percentage)



# split to train and test data
split_idx = int(tiles.shape[0] * 0.9)

train = tiles[:split_idx]
val = tiles[split_idx:]

y_train = tiles[:split_idx]
y_val = tiles[split_idx:]


# Build or load model
if os.path.exists(MODEL_SAVE_PATH):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_SAVE_PATH)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name='rmse')])

    # scale data before training
    train = train / 255.
    val = val / 255.

    y_train = y_train / 255.
    y_val = y_val / 255.

    # train
    history = model.fit(train,
                        y_train,
                        validation_data=(val, y_val),
                        epochs=0)  # Adjust epochs as needed

    # Save the model
    model.save(MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
else:
    model = build_model(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name='rmse')])

    # scale data before training
    train = train / 255.
    val = val / 255.

    y_train = y_train / 255.
    y_val = y_val / 255.

    # train
    history = model.fit(train,
                        y_train,
                        validation_data=(val, y_val),
                        epochs=50)  # Adjust epochs as needed

    # Save the model
    model.save(MODEL_SAVE_PATH)

# predict on E2
img2 = cv2.imread('images/E2.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = np.array(img2, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
idxs, tiles2, overlap = extract_image_tiles_with_overlap(WIDTH, WIDTH // 2, img2, center_tile_width, overlap_percentage)

# scale data
tiles2 = tiles2 / 255.

preds = model.predict(tiles2)

# Check model output range
print("Max prediction value:", np.max(preds))
print("Min prediction value:", np.min(preds))

# Invert colors in predictions
inverted_preds = 1.0 - preds

# Ensure values are within valid range
inverted_preds = np.clip(inverted_preds, 0, 1)

# Reconstruct inverted predictions with cropping center part of the tile
reconstructed = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)

# Reconstruction process
for (y_start, y_end, x_start, x_end), tile in zip(idxs, inverted_preds[:, :, :, -1]):
    y_end = min(y_end, img.shape[0])
    x_end = min(x_end, img.shape[1])

    # Calculate the crop size based on the size of the original tile without overlap
    crop_size = WIDTH

    # Rescale the tile to the original size (WIDTH + overlap)
    rescaled_tile = cv2.resize(tile, (WIDTH + overlap, WIDTH + overlap))

    # Crop the center part of the rescaled tile
    center_crop = rescaled_tile[overlap//2:overlap//2+crop_size, overlap//2:overlap//2+crop_size]

    # Update the reconstructed image directly with the cropped tile
    reconstructed[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end] = (center_crop * 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Apply binary dilation and erosion to enhance the tile boundaries
# Apply non-local means denoising
denoised_reconstructed = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(reconstructed, h=10, templateWindowSize=7, searchWindowSize=21)



im = Image.fromarray(denoised_reconstructed)
im = im.resize(INIT_SIZE)
im.show()
```

***The updated answer ends here.***

---

So I think this is mainly about post processing and visualization of your data:

[image]

I visualize like this now:

```
# predict on E2
img2 = cv2.imread('images/E2.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (1408, 1408), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = np.array(img2, np.uint8)

# extract tiles from images
idxs, tiles2 = extract_image_tiles(WIDTH, img2)

# scale data
tiles2 = tiles2 / 255.

preds = model.predict(tiles2)

# Check model output range
print("Max prediction value:", np.max(preds))
print("Min prediction value:", np.min(preds))

# Invert colors in predictions
inverted_preds = 1.0 - preds

# Ensure values are within valid range
inverted_preds = np.clip(inverted_preds, 0, 1)

# Reconstruct inverted predictions
reconstructed = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)

# Reconstruction process
for tile, (y_start, y_end, x_start, x_end) in zip(inverted_preds[:, :, :, -1], idxs):
    y_end = min(y_end, img.shape[0])
    x_end = min(x_end, img.shape[1])
    reconstructed[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end] = (tile * 255).astype(np.uint8)

im = Image.fromarray(reconstructed)
im = im.resize(INIT_SIZE)
im.show()
```

I can already clearly see the black square. So next I will be trying some thresholding to get enhance that visibility in post-processing.

I am thinking of something like that:

```
# Threshold value (adjust as needed)
threshold = 0.9 #0.45

# Thresholding
binary_output = (reconstructed >= threshold).astype(np.uint8) * 255

# Second visualization
im_binary = Image.fromarray(binary_output)
im_binary = im_binary.resize(INIT_SIZE)
im_binary.show()
```

Which leaves me with this:

[image]

Not sure how good this scales across your full dataset, but this is definitely in the ball-park for some morphological operators in post-processing.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. My problem is not the small black box. This is some bad pixel. My problem is the square tile border lines. As for the threshold, it doesn't offer me something. If I put another value I can still see the square tiles. The thing is why at the reconstruction stage, the square tile lines appear.

Comment: okay. So you are interested in the full image. Yet reconstructed?

Comment: Yes, I have tiled the initial images, trained the model with those tiles and now I want to reconstruct the predicted image. Which seems ok (the background of it) but for some reason I can see the square tiles grid uppon it.

Comment: understood will look into that later today.

Comment: FYI I just added a new code where I use another patches and reconstruction method. The image still has the square tiles but you can see it better.

Comment: I think I solved it. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It partially works, I mean it totally ruins the colors (not in this small example in the post). And after using the strides and overlap in the patches generation and in the reconstruction process, it is very weird to me that you still the square border tiles are there! And you need denoising to remove them! I 'll take it a look later also.

Comment: As mentioned the squared border lines will always be there if you do not denoise or aggregate pixels. This is the nature of things, when you crop and stitch. This is a trade-off you need to make. Alternatively reconstruct the full image, if an appropriate size fits into memory of your processor.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the bounty - appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, I opened a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78029815/grid-lines-in-produced-image-how-to-upscale-without-introducing-them) where I am dealing with those lines through the cnn network, if you are interested!